# Android BLE scanning with PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-ble

A few days ago, I was able to successfully get Android to scan for BLE devices using `PendingIntents`. I'm having trouble today getting the PendingIntent to receive any callback data, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why.

I'm using the following function as defined in the Android docs:

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner:

```
startScan(List<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

I have added the following permissions to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I have also declared that I'm using this receiver as so:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.PendingIntentScanReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND" />
        <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID" />
        <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the implementation of this `PendingIntentScanReceiver`:

```
public class PendingIntentScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Hello there.");
    }
}
```

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S8 and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248178/oreo-ble-scanner-startscan-with-pendingintent-not-working-on-samsung-device) that I shouldn't be passing `null` for my scan filters (because that doesn't work well on Samsung devices I guess?).

I have also tried moving the `startScan` call from background service to MainApplication to MainActivity, but none of these seem to improve the outcome.

By the way, my `startScan` code looks like this:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        ScanSettings settings = (new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)).build();

        List<ScanFilter> listOfFiters = new ArrayList<>();
        ScanFilter.Builder builder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
        ScanFilter filter = builder.build();
        listOfFiters.add(filter);

        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PendingIntentScanReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 42, intent, 0);
        int scanRes = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(listOfFiters, settings, pendingIntent);

        // (scanRes is always 0 during my tests)
    }
```

My question is: Why is "Hello there." never printed? Is there something that I've forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Oreo, BLE scanner startScan with PendingIntent not working on Samsung device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248178/oreo-ble-scanner-startscan-with-pendingintent-not-working-on-samsung-device/54198717#54198717)

Please, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198717/2115352

TL;DR:

1. There is no need to set an empty filter. You may give *null* to `startScan`.
2. Set action in your Filter. The same that you use in `<receiver>`'s `<intent-filter>`
3. Set only one action there, and make it unique to your app, for example:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.PendingIntentScanReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.ACTION_FOUND" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

4. Remove the Extras from intent filter. You specify there actions, not extras.
5. `bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()` returns *null* when Bluetooth is disabled.

Answer (score -2):

As stated on Official Docs

> With limited exceptions, apps cannot use their manifest to register for implicit broadcasts. They can still register for these broadcasts at runtime, and they can use the manifest to register for explicit broadcasts targeted specifically at their app.

I think it's pretty much related to how background tasks work rather than `ble` issue. Kindly go through with the api changes of android `Oreo` [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts). I think you should implement an foreground service to do those things.